# Conditional implementation of javax or jakarta servlet API depending on which is on classpath

Tags: java, maven, antlr4, open-source, jakarta-migration

I'm working on an open-source library that uses `servlet-api`. Consider this simple interface:

```java
import javax.servlet.Filter;

interface HttpFilter extends Filter {
}
```

I want to generalize `HttpFilter` to extend either `javax.servlet.Filter` or `jakarta.servlet.Filter` depending on which one is on the classpath. I should stress that the library is **neither** Spring nor a Spring Boot based.

The Maven dependencies section would look like this:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is a suggestion to use something like ANTLR 4 Maven plugin to generate sources on the fly, but I haven't done this before and don't know how complicated it is. Before doing further investment into it, I'd like to hear the community's opinion as there might be even better choices.

Comment: You can't have a single type which dynamically changes what it extends.

Comment: @Michael: If the source is changed before compile time (e.g., by ANTLR), is it still dynamic? For me, dynamic means the relationship is determined at runtime.

Comment: Depends what you mean by compile-time. If it's compile-time *of your library*, then ANTLR or any other library isn't able to do anything special that you couldn't write by hand. If it's compile-time of the end-user of your library, then maybe you could do something.

Comment: First ANTLR is a parser generator ... and not a code generator ... furthermore based on my experience using inheritance in interfaces is a bad idea... you might define interfaces without any relationship to jakarta nor javax and provde two different implementation which use jakarata or javax... apart from that all I would decide to go only with jakarta area...(https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.servlet JEE8) ... in particular JEE 9+

Comment: BTW: You might think of a code genertor based on templates or alike ... (very simple one: https://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/) or even more complex based on velocity or alike?... So you could generate two different sets of code...